# Local cocoapods sources in debugger displayed in asm in XCode 8

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode8, macos-sierra

I am developing number of pods and store them in my own private repo. So I can install pods as usual, from this repository `pod "SomePod"`, or install locally (Development pods) with `pod "SomePod", :path => "~/SomePath/ToPod"`

When using local pods (2-nd variant) in Xcode 8 I have no possibility to debug, because all sources, that come from pods, are displayed in asm, not in Objective-C, that they are written. In Xcode 7 everything was fine.
When using remote pods (default way, 1-st variant) pods are displayed in Objective-C, but editing them doesn't have impact on real pod sources, because I edit copied from repository version.

I use Cocoapods 1.0.1 version. In Xcode
*"Debug" -> "Debug Workflow" -> "Always Use Disassembly"* is disabled.

Does anyone face the same problem? Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks for any help.

**Update:** found out, that this happened because of macOS Sierra and not depends on Xcode version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently found the solution. The issue was in workspace file (don't know, what exactly was wrong there). Solve it by creating new `xcworkspace` for the projects (I use different name, but I believe, there wasn't naming problem).